# Spring boot http request always handled by the same method

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to perform the user login functionality in my spring boot application, but it seems that all the http requests are handled by the same method, means that they're redirected into the same URL.

Here is my login controller

```
    package com.lyes.webmail.demo.controllers;


    import com.lyes.webmail.demo.DAO.UserDAO;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

   @Controller
   public class LoginController {

@Autowired
UserDAO asi;


@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(){
    System.out.println("i'm here"); return "login";
}



@RequestMapping(value = "/connection", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String logMe(@RequestParam String email, @RequestParam String password){
    if(asi.login(email,password)){
        System.out.println("success");
        return "home";
    }else{
        System.out.println("failure");
        return "error";
    }
}

}
```

my login form

```
               <form id="login-form" class="form" action="/connection" method="POST">
                    <h3 class="text-center text-info">Login to lyes web mail</h3>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username" class="text-info">Email:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="username" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="text-info">Password:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md" value="Login">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

And the `SecurityConfig` which extends the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in order to render the login page as the welcome page.

```
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected  void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("lyes");
    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll();
   }
}
```

In the login controller method i've put a sysout to analyse the behaviour, and the message `i'm here` is printed twice, the first time when the login page loads and the second time when i submit the form.

Any suggestions !??

Comment: You secured everything BUT `/login`. So when submitting, one needs to be authentication if not you will be redirected to the login page. Or in other words with your current setup you cannot login. Also you shouldn't be using your `/connection` method but let Spring Security (which you are using) handle the login, you are currently working around the framework you decided to use.

Comment: How can spring security handle the login ? I would like to point out that I don't want to use spring JPA.

Comment: Instead of blindly adding frameworks I strongly suggest to read the docs on how things work. Spring Security does authentication and authorization. That is what the `formLogin` stuff is doing, it will also handle the POST to `/login` (which you should be doing). It will then delegate to an `AuthenticationProvider` which will use a `UserDetailsService` to obtain the username and check the password. The only thing you need to do is provide an adapter for the `UserDetailsService` to your `UserDao` (or use the default and provide the queries).